# Proper output for the program

Tags: python

```
import itertools 

file = open('out.txt', 'w')
variations = itertools.product('abc', repeat=3) 

for variations in variations: 
    variation_string = "" 

    for letter in variations: 
        variation_string += letter 

    file.write(variation_string)

file.close()
```

The output from the above program is like a clustered state:

```
aaaaabaacabaabbabcacaacbaccbaababbacbbabbbbbcbcabcbbcccaacabcaccbacbbcbcccaccb­ccc
```

Can you modify the program so that the output would be in a line after line that is the first line of the output would be `aaa` and the next line would be `aab` and the next would be `aac` and so on...

```
aaa
aab
aac
```

Comment: "can you modify the program"?  No.  We can't.  You must do your own homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a revised code that fixes a few other issues in addition to the mentioned problem:

```
import itertools
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for variation in itertools.product('abc', repeat=3):
        f.write(str.join("", variation) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

After your `file.write`, add another `file.write('\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to print that list to stdout:

```
>>> for variation in itertools.product('abc', repeat=3):
...     print(''.join(variation) + '\n'),
```

Writing it to your file is left as an exercise...